# How to solve congruence modulo equations?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, congruences

While studying [Affine Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher) in cryptography it tells that we need to solve a system of modulo congruence equations.

The equations are:

1. $8\alpha+\beta\equiv 15 \pmod{26}$
2. $5\alpha+\beta\equiv 16 \pmod{26}$

Could anyone tell how to solve these equations.

Comment: $\beta\equiv 15-8\alpha\,\Rightarrow\, 5\alpha + (15-8\alpha)\equiv 15-3\alpha\equiv 16\iff 3\alpha\equiv -1\equiv -27$   

$\stackrel{:3}\iff \alpha\equiv -9\equiv 17$ mod $26$. So $8(17)+\beta\equiv 15\iff \beta\equiv 9$ mod $26$.

Comment: @user31415:That's a good answer.Could you tell me how $-1 \equiv -27$ came?Also why always we place equivalence symbol in these equations when an equal symbol is enough to get $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: $-1 = -27 + 26(1)$, so $-1$ and $-27$ give same remainders when divided by $26$. Definition: $a\equiv b\pmod{\! n}\!\iff\! n\mid a-b$ or i.e. $a,b$ leave same remainders when divided by $n$. It is nitpicking about notation whether you can write equality symbols in place of equivalences there, but I would just write equivalences everywhere. I could later divide both sides by $3$ because $(26,3)=1$. It is because $26\mid 3(\alpha-(-9))\!\iff\! 26\mid \alpha-(-9)$, which may make this division property more apparent. Remember Fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: @user31415:Okay that's right.Yeah I'll go with equivalence.Is it sure that for any numbers m and n if (m,n)=1 you could divide both sides of the equivalence by n?How did you get -27 in the R.H.S?Is it a guess or is there any strategy to follow for finding -27?Also couldn't get how you wrote $26\mid 3(\alpha-(-9))$ while I think we just need to consider $26\mid 3\alpha$?

Comment: @user31415:Yeah got it.Could you tell how did you changed $26\mid \alpha-(-9)$ into $\alpha\equiv-9 \equiv 17$ mod 26?Does this use the same logic you stated in previous comment?Also how to find the value of $\alpha$ from  $\alpha\equiv-9 \equiv 17$ mod 26?Is it($\alpha$)  -9 or 17?

Comment: Sorry for deleting the comment. Here is the comment you've just replied to: Yes: $(a,m)=1,\, ak\equiv al\pmod{\!m}\,\Rightarrow\, k\equiv l\pmod{\!m}$. More generally, $ak\equiv al\pmod{\!m}\!\iff\! k\equiv l\pmod{\!\frac{m}{(a,m)}}$. As I said, $-1$, $-27$ leave same remainders mod $26$, so they're equivalent. The reason I wrote it as $-27$ instead of something like $25$ is because $27$ is divisible by $3$. So I could simply divide by $3$ and remove the $3$ from $3\alpha$. $3\alpha\equiv -27\pmod{\! 26}\!\iff\! 26\mid 3\alpha-(-27)\!\iff\! 26\mid 3(\alpha-(-9))$.

Comment: Remember definition: $a\equiv b\pmod{\!m}\!\iff\! m\mid a-b$. So here $26\mid \alpha-(-9)\!\iff\! \alpha\equiv -9\pmod{\! 26}$. $-9\equiv 17\pmod{\!26}$ because $-9$, $17$ leave same remainders mod $26$. So you now know $\alpha$ can be written as either $26k-9$ or $26m+17$ (or in fact $26l+43$, etc.). Your teacher would normally want you to leave it as $\alpha\equiv 17\pmod{\! 26}$, since $0\le 17<26$. mod can be used in two ways: as an equivalence relation with $\equiv$ symbols as you do here, or as an operation: $\alpha \bmod {26}=17$, where we must have $0\le 17<26$.

Comment: @user31415:Okay that's good.Nice explanation.Does this mean the value of $\alpha$ is 17?Also how to know whether an equivalence equation would produce an unique solution as seen here if the value of $\alpha$ is only 17?

Comment: The only thing we can know out of the system of congruences (and it is precisely the exact thing it tells us) is that $\alpha$ leaves remainder $17$ when divided by $26$ and $\beta$ leaves remainder $9$ when divided by $26$. By definition the remainder $r$ when $a$ is divided by $m$ satisfies $a=km+r$ with $r\in [0,m)$. It is just a convention that it is in $[0,m)$. Sometimes it could be more convenient to leave it in $(-m,0]$, e.g. leave it as $-1$ when it would otherwise be $m-1$ for some large $m$ that is hard to write.

Comment: What this system of congruences tells us is precisely that $\alpha\in\{\ldots,26(-2)+17,26(-1)+17,26(0)+17,26(1)+17,26(2)+17,\ldots\}$ and $\beta\in\{\ldots,26(-2)+9,26(-1)+9,26(0)+9, 26(1)+9,26(2)+9,\ldots\}$ - it tells us nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @user31415:Oh that's right.I couldn't understand your second comment.Could you explain it a bit more simple.

Answer (score 1):

On subtraction, $$3\alpha\equiv-1\pmod{26}\equiv-1+2\cdot26$$

As $(3,26)=1,$ $$\alpha\equiv17\pmod{26}$$

and $$\beta\equiv15-8\alpha\pmod{26}\equiv?$$

Comment: :Could you tell how did you get (-1+2.26) on the R.H.S in the first line of the answer?

Comment: @justin, As $52\equiv0\pmod{26},51\equiv-1$

Comment: :Could you tell how did you get 52?Do you mean to say that when we subtract these equations we would get $52 \equiv 0 \pmod{26}$?

Comment: @justin, We need to find a value of $y$ such that $3|(26y-1)$  . By observation, $y=2$ is one of such values

Comment: :Could you tell why do we need to get a value of y for $3|(26y-1)$ when the equation is just $3\alpha\equiv-1\pmod{26}$ where there is no y?

Answer (score 0):

Just making @labbhattacharjee's answer a bit more clear :

$$8\alpha + \beta \equiv 15 \pmod{26} \longrightarrow(1)$$
$$5\alpha + \beta \equiv 16 \pmod{26} \longrightarrow(2)$$

$(1) - (2) \implies 3\alpha \equiv -1 \pmod{26}$

Directly proceeding from here to get $3\alpha \equiv 25 \pmod{26}$ makes it difficult to isolate $\alpha$(unless we find a suitable value for the equation $3\alpha = 26n + 25$ or say, we are ready to work it out; but here, $n = 1$ is a suitable solution and hence you may choose this) , hence we take the nearest multiple of $26$ whose predecessor is a multiple of $3$, i.e., $52$.
So we get $3\alpha = 51$ and $\alpha = 17$.Plugging this in any of the two congruence equations will get you the path of solving for $\beta$.